# Context specific navigation in Genshi and CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy, genshi

Using the Genshi templating engine with CherryPy, I need to have a context-specific site navigation which displays a different menu for logged in users.

Users are identified by a CherryPy session.

What would be the best way to show a different menu for logged in users?

Comment: How are users logging in?

Comment: Login is performed via a user/pass which authenticates against the database and sets a session including an auth key.  It uses this: http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We check to see if the user is logged in...

```
import cherrypy
from genshi.template import TemplateLoader

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
tmpl = loader.load('index.html')

if(cherrypy.session.get('_cp_Email')):
    return tmpl.generate(title='Geddit').render('html', LoggedIn=True)
else:
    return tmpl.generate(title='Geddit').render('html', LoggedIn=False)
```

your template would like something like this...

```
            if (LoggedIn) {
              # Logged In menu
            } else {
              # not Logged In menu
            }
```

If they are we send a variable to the template to show Log Out instead of Login.

We're using this for Authentication...

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions

Include the comments for security reasons.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'm using the same auth method as you.  I was thinking there was a native Genshi way of doing it, but essentially I'll be having a whole different menu system for logged in users.  On that basis, I suppose I could send the template a menu type as a string, then have Genshi check for menu_type.  Therefore CherryPy will govern the decision logic, whilst maintaining Genshi as the presentation engine.  Do you agree?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you could do it in the same template.  But you would want to send either menu template via include to keep it modular...  http://genshi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/template/#genshi.template.base.Template.INCLUDE

Comment: This article might help explain it better... http://renesd.blogspot.com/2010/02/genshi-templates-headerfooter-templates.html Also this thread is helpful... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genshi/ja7eM3y36dE